# Correct way to use async/await inside Jquery loop

Tags: jquery, async-await

I am having the below JQuery code in my script. In this I am trying to show the loading icon when series of ajax calls happens inside **saveQuestion** function.

But the loading functionality is not happened but the calling ajax call is happened in  sequence.

I am trying the below code. Please suggest any idea

```
$(document).on("click", ".update_qualify_question", function (e) {  

    var btnObj  = $(".update_qualify_question");
    var btnTxt = btnObj.text();
    btnObj.html('Processing <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    btnObj.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    
    (async function() {
        $(this).closest('.conditional_qa_portion').find(".current_question").each(async function(){
            await saveQuestion($(this), 1);
        })
    
    })();
       
        btnObj.html(btnTxt); 
        btnObj.removeAttr('disabled');  
                
});
```

Comment: You will have to make sure to call `btnObj.html(btnTxt);` and `btnObj.removeAttr('disabled');` when the saving is done. Couldn't you simply remove the async function around the .each loop? You await in the loop anyway.

Comment: `$(this).closest('.conditional_qa_portion').find(".current_question")` - it won't be found in your case, because now `this`  = `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that your function isn't awaiting on the results of the asynchronous code, this means you are changing the button text then immediately changing it back, which leads to the appearance that the text hasn't changed.

```js
btnObj.html('Processing <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
// not awaited so don't stop execution
(async function() {
  $(this)
    .closest('.conditional_qa_portion')
    .find(".current_question")
    .each(async function() {await saveQuestion($(this), 1);});
})();
// ran immediately
btnObj.html(btnText);
```

there are two issues with awaiting on the code, you have the async call in the `.each` which has no way to be awaited for and the anonymous function you created and called immediately.

you could do something like this using async/await:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".update_qualify_question", async function (e) {  
    const btnObj  = $(e.currentTarget);
    const btnTxt = btnObj.text();
    btnObj.html('Processing <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>');
    btnObj.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    // not sure what element you wanted to do closest on since you had nested function so this wasn't the button (which is what I believe you meant)
    const elms = btnObj      
        .closest('.conditional_qa_portion')
        .find(".current_question")
        .toArray();
    for(const elm of elms) {
        await saveQuestion($(elm), 1);
    }
    btnObj.html(btnTxt); 
    btnObj.removeAttr('disabled');              
});
```

With this we can wait till each data call is done before allowing the button to be clicked again. we use `.toArray()` to get the list so that we can await on the results in a for of loop since the `.each()` has no way for us to await on the results.